# How to render an animation stored in a collada file format using Vulkan

Tags: c++, blender, vulkan, collada

I'm following the [Vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Loading_models) but it doesn't cover animation. I have finished reading the loading models chapter.

My goal is to implement functionality in my Vulkan application that will render a 3d animation which is stored in a COLLADA file format.

I would like advice for how to implement this functionality in my Vulkan application.
Posting example code would be helpful.
Since I'm following the tutorial my code is the same as what's on the loading models chapter.

PS: I don't want to do skeletal animation or skinned animation or anything complicated. I just want to know how to read the collada file so I can figure out how to implement this in my application

Comment: This question might be better on the Blender SE: https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think not. Because my question is more related with how to implement this in c++ using Vulkan than the mechanics of blender.

Comment: Vulkan has nothing to do with this. If you can set the "location rotation and scale" of an entity, and you can change those values and see the results in the program, then you have everything that is needed for animation. Animating something is just a matter of changing those values at various intervals. And for the most part, that has nothing to do with your graphics API, save for how you send the data to the system.

Comment: I know that I can change the location, rotation and scale of an object by changing the model matrix. But what I'm asking is: how do I render an animation that's stored in a collada file format.

And no, I can't see the results in my program because I created the animation in Blender, that is: I haven't hard coded the animation in my program because that's not what I want to do.

Comment: This is currently way too broad as you haven't even explained which parts you don't know how to do. Do you know how to read a collada file? Do you know how to read the animation data from a collada file? Do you know how skeletal animation works? Do you need/want to do skinned animation? All those topics are things you need to read up on in proper sources, as they are too large for an SO question

Comment: I don't know how skeletal animation works. I don't want to do anything complicated I just want to know how to read a collada file and the animation data from the file.

Comment: Vulkan is not some kind of premade video player. I suppose you either need to read the documentation and make your own parser, or you use someone else's parser. Basic animation is just a series of singular renders, so I guess you just do whatever the tutorial does and put it on repeat, while making modifications to the scene between each frame.

Comment: What parsers would you recommend?

Comment: I tend to use Assimp